# How to write three equalities in the same line with another under the first equality

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

How to write three equalities in the same line with another under the first equality?

Similar to this:

```
A = B = D      
  = E
```

What I want is that `E` exactly under `B`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

It's quite straightforward using `align` from `amsmath`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  A & = B = D\\
    & = E
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

or `align*` to suppress the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  A & = B = D\\
    & = E
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```